# Environment exmp undefined. \begin{exmp}! in aims document class

Tags: document-classes, examples

How can I make **examples** to be labeled and cited (Like theorems and lemmas) in a aims document class? 
I used

```
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
```

but was not working.

Answer (score 1):

Place a label inside the example and use `\ref{<label>}` to reference it. Don't forget to compile two times.

```
\documentclass{AIMS}

\usepackage{amsthm} 
\newtheorem{example}{Example} 


\begin{document}

\begin{example}\label{key}
test
\end{example}


\ref{key}

\end{document}
```